# how to solve this error in mongodb aggregation: TypeError: ({$unwind:{path:"$tags", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}}) is not iterable :

Tags: mongodb-query

i have a collection

```
    [{
    "_id": {"$oid": "63873b95c7e956270e734f3c"},
    "employeeId": "emp1",
    "users": [{"name": "Allen","registered": true},
             {"name": "Henry","registered": true},
             {"name": "Adam","registered": false}],
     "tags": ["good","excellent","average"]
    },{
   "_id": {"$oid": "63873c05c7e956270e734f3d"},
   "employeeId": "emp2",
   "users": [{"name": "Federick","registered": false},
             {"name": "Mary","registered": true},
             {"name": "Sam","registered": false} ],
  "tags": ["poor","excellent", "good"]}
  ,{
  "_id": {"$oid": "63873c1fc7e956270e734f3e"},
  "employeeId": "emp3",
  "users": [ {"name": "john", "registered": true},
           {"name": "jack","registered": true},
           {"name": "elle", "registered": false } ],
   "tags": ["very good", "excellent", "good" ]}]
```

i am trying to groupby tags and employee with count of employees under each tag,expected output is

[image]

i am getting the correct output by python code which is

```
  pipeline = [{"$unwind":"$users"},{"$match":{"users.registered":True}},
            
            {"$unwind":"$tags"},
            
            {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$tags","employees":{"$push": {"employeeId":"$employeeId"}},
            "employees" : { "$addToSet" : "$employeeId" }, 
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    
            {"$project":{"_id":1,"employees":1,"size":{"$size":"$employees"}}},
            {"$sort" : { "size": -1 } },
              ]

rec = db.ratings.aggregate(pipeline)
```

but its giving error in mongoshell
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$tags",
      "employees": {
        "$push": "$employeeId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "employees": 1,
      "size": {
        "$size": "$employees"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "size": -1
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aBy11Z0zEJG)